# Temperature conversion in Python: How to convert int (0 - 255) which is a byte object to degrees Celsius in Python

Tags: python, c, arduino, data-conversion

We are currently working on an Arduino Uno project and getting stuck at the conversion of the integer data to degrees celcius. This code is working however it converts the binary packed data (\xd01) etc. to int (0-255). Our question is: how to convert the integer value to read out a certain degree of Celcius. For example: int 2 = 2 degrees celcius and 255 = 35 degrees Celcius

This is our Python code with the Pyserial module

```
import serial
import struct
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 19200, timeout=5)
while True:
    tempdata = ser.read(2)
    x= struct.unpack('!BB', tempdata)
    print(x)
```

And this is the code of the temperature conversion on our Arduino Uno, it is written in C.

```
    #define F_CPU 16E6
```

// output on USB = PD1 = board pin 1
// datasheet p.190; F_OSC = 16 MHz & baud rate = 19.200
#define UBBRVAL 51

void uart_init()
{
    // set the baud rate
    UBRR0H = 0;
    UBRR0L = UBBRVAL;
    // disable U2X mode
    UCSR0A = 0;
    // enable transmitter
    UCSR0B = _BV(TXEN0);
    // set frame format : asynchronous, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity
    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(UCSZ00);
}
void transmit(uint8_t data)
{
    // wait for an empty transmit buffer
    // UDRE is set when the transmit buffer is empty
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    // send the data
    UDR0 = data;
}

void init_adc()
{
    // ref=Vcc, left adjust the result (8 bit resolution),
    // select channel 0 (PC0 = input)
    ADMUX = (1<<REFS0);
    // enable the ADC & prescale = 128
    ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0);
}
uint8_t get_adc_value()
{

    //ADMUX |= 1
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC); // start conversion
    loop_until_bit_is_clear(ADCSRA, ADSC);
    return ADC; // 8-bit resolution, left adjusted
}

/*
((value / 1024 * 5) - 0. 5) * 100
*/

int main(void) {
    init_adc();
    uart_init();
    //int x;
    while(1)
    {

        int x = get_adc_value();
        int temp = ((((float) x / 1024) * 5) - 0.5) * 100;
        transmit(temp);
        _delay_ms(200);
    }
}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question: we would like to convert the integers to degrees celcius but dont know how. The serial port reads integer values from 0 to 255 since it is an 8 byte object

Comment: '((((float) x / 1024) * 5) - 0.5) * 100;' that is terribru. It's easily simplified to avoid the float operations.

Comment: Is the temp value converison a linear mapping, ie an 'y=mx+c' ?  If so, and you have two points with values in each system, (which you seem to have, 2=2, and 255=35), then you have 2 simultaneous equations to get m and c.  If it's not linear, use a lookup table.

Comment: The conversion from C source seems to be linear with 0 -> -50.00 ° and 256 -> +75.00 °. Is it what you want to translate into Python?

Comment: It is a linear equatation: the clock has 1024 cycles and the Arduino has an supply of 5 volt. Each specified voltage has an degree attached to it with an total offset of 0.5. So yeah this is what i want to retranslate back into Python!

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from ADC value to temp will most likely depend on what type of temperature sensor you are using. I recommend looking a the datasheet of your temp sensor.
If you are using a 'TMP36', you can convert using this formula:

> Centigrade temperature = [(analog voltage in mV) - 500] / 10

Source: https://learn.adafruit.com/tmp36-temperature-sensor/using-a-temp-sensor

If you a using a thermocouple, you'll need to look at the table of correspondance for the type you are using (e.g. type K: https://www.omega.fr/temperature/Z/pdf/z204-206.pdf)

Comment: We are using an TMP36GZ sensor. So that is the right one! However i will try to convert that formula into the 1024 cycle one and see if it works.

Comment: (207,), (211,), (210,) It still spitting out these values

Comment: Just used your basic formula btw.

Comment: that is the way struct.unpack work, you could use `x = tempdata[0] * 256 + tempdata[1]` or `x = tempdata[1] * 256 + tempdata[0]` depending on the endianess